# Replacing only part of the Title element in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm looking into a way to replace the portion of the title element using the Title service in Angular. So basically, I have a `<title>WebApp | title of the current page</title>`. I want to replace the part of the 'title of the current page' whenever I navigated to different routes.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Angular has an injectable service for this called `Title`. An official guide on how to use the service can be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title).

Here is a [blog article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/dynamic-page-titles-in-angular-98ce20b5c334) showing you how to exapnd this concept and dynamically change the title on routing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Title Service](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title)

In  app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = "WebApp | ";

  public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }

  ngOnInt(){
    this.setTitle( 'Something Else' );
  }

  public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle( title + newTitle );
  }
}
```

Or

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = "";

  public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }

  ngOnInt(){
    this.title = this.titleService.getTitle();
  }

  public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
    let fistPart = this.title.substring(0, this.title.lastIndexOf('|'));
    this.titleService.setTitle( fistPart + newTitle );
  }
}
```

In app.component.html (root component)

```
<title>WebApp | title of the current page</title>
```

Comment: I have done this. I do not want to do this; I want is for the WebApp to be set in the index.html `<title>` element.

Comment: @rpmansion your  angular app is a single page application, basically this is added to title tag in index.html

Comment: I get that but I do not want the part of it to be set in app.component, I want to partial of it only to be replace on app.component or anywhere where the TitleService is used.

Comment: @rpmansion may be you can use the `getTitle() ` in title srvice and get the current title and replace the string that you dont need after the character `|`